# Bash Zenity Spaces Forms - Reading input

Tags: bash, forms, search, find, zenity

Hi I am new with Bash and I have a problem with reading input with spaces.
I use zenity, this is my code :

```
RESULT=$(zenity --forms --title="Title"\
    --text="Text"\
    --add-entry="File Name"\
    --add-entry="Directory")


    NAME=$(echo $RESULT| cut -d '|' -f 1)
    DIRECTORY=$(echo $RESULT| cut -d '|' -f 2)

    if [ $DIRECTORY ]; then
        COMMAND="$COMMAND $DIRECTORY "
    fi

    if [ $NAME ]; then
      COMMAND="$COMMAND -name $NAME "
    fi

    find $COMMAND
```

When I am trying to search file in folder - "Name Space" it does not work, because the space sign, the same with name.

If you know how can I do it with spaces, please help.
Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code, fixed for some problems (it works now):

```
#!/bin/bash

result="$(zenity --forms --title="Title"\
    --text="Text"\
    --add-entry="File Name"\
    --add-entry="Directory")"


    name="$(echo "$result"| cut -d '|' -f 1)"
    directory="$(echo "$result"| cut -d '|' -f 2)"

    if [ "$directory" ]; then
        command="$directory"
    fi

    if [ "$name" ]; then
      command="$command$name"
    fi

    find "$command"
```

Some comments:

1) It is very advisable to use double quotes when you are assigning a value to a variable or when you are expanding a variable. That precludes `word splitting`. See [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html).

2) Avoid using variables in UPPERCASE - the Bash shell uses variables in UPPERCASE and you should avoid doing so to avoid a name collision.

3) Some of your variable concatenation had some mistakes, I fixed those.

Note: your user should enter the directory name including the forward slashes, such as `/folder/` or `/` (for root directory).

I hope this helps!

Comment: I have another question. how the command should look like when I want to find all files by type example mp3? It does not work
find: ‘/home/mint/- Disc 1/*.mp3’

Comment: You should look into the `iname` option for `find` (ex: find -iname *.mp3). see: https://linux.die.net/man/1/find . Whenever you get stuck on something, a good point to start is to look for the man page of the command, in this case you could search for "find man linux". Good luck!